# amcharts - ClockHand - How to add a ToolTip

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm follow this example to build a Gauge Graph with AmCharts: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gauge-with-bands/

After some modifications, I added a new ClockHand element as can be seen in the image below:
[In the gauge graph, I adde a second ClockHand (blue color) and try to add a ToolTip.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElYyc.png).

But when I tryed to use this ToolTip, It' not showing in the correct position. I'm using this code:

```
var hand2 = chartdivGauge.hands.push(new am4charts.ClockHand());
hand2.innerRadius = am4core.percent(95);
hand2.radius = am4core.percent(100);
hand2.startWidth = 20;
hand2.pin.disabled = true;
hand2.value = 50; 
hand2.fill = am4core.color('blue');
hand2.stroke = am4core.color('blue');
hand2.tooltipText = "AAA";
```

So, how can I fix that? How can I put this Tooltip in the right position, close to clockhand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @martynasma, I've got the answer in GitHub amcharts forum, take a look:

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2778

> A ClockHand is a big element, consisting of many sub-elements.

I suggest you put tooltip on its hand sub-element:

hand2.hand.tooltipText = "My Tool Tip";